# Looping through a nested JSON object format in datatables

Tags: javascript, json, django, datatables

I'm looking to iterate through a JSON object in javascript and I also, wonder that whether my json format is correct and efficient or not. https://datatables.net/ I want to show the relationship between tables in a single table. For example, I want to get:

| ID | hospital date | type | suffix | description | name | prefix | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-01-2021 | cov | G | result | Oslo | S | result |
| 2 | 03-03-2021 | cov | G | result2 | Oslo | S | result2 |
| 3 | 05-05-2021 | cov | G | result3 | Kiev | S | result3 |

**models.py**

```
class Samples(models.Model):
    hospital_date = models.DateField()
    source_sample = models.ForeignKey(SourceSample, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    projects = models.ForeignKey(Projects, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
class SourceSample(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    suffix = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=256)
class Projects(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    prefix = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

**json**

```
    [{
      "id":1,
      "hospital_date":"01-01-2021",
      "source_samples":{
         "type":"cov",
         "suffix":"G",
         "description":"result"
      },
      "projects":{
         "name":"Oslo",
         "prefix":"S",
         "description":"result"
      }
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "hospital_date":"03-03-2021",
      "source_samples":{
         "type":"cov",
         "suffix":"G",
         "description":"result2"
      },
      "projects":{
         "name":"Oslo",
         "prefix":"S",
         "description":"result2"
      }
   }]
```

**js**

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
          "ajax": {
            url: "/json",
            type: "GET"
          },
          "columns": [{"data": "id"}, 
                     {"data": "hospital_date"},
                     {"data": 'projects.name'},
                     {"data": 'projects.prefix'},
                     {"data": 'projects.description'},
                     {"data": 'source_samples.type'},
                     {"data": 'source_samples.suffix'},
                     {"data": 'source_samples.description'}
                     ]
```

**serializer.py**

```
class SourceSamplesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SourceSamples
        fields = ['type', 'suffix', 'description']
class ProjectsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Projects
        fields = ['name', 'prefix', 'description']
class SamplesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    projects = ProjectsSerializer(read_only=True)
    source_samples = SourceSamplesSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Samples
        fields = ['hospital_date', 'projects', 'source_samples']
```

**view.py**

```
def samples_json(request):
    serializer = SamplesSerializer(Samples.objects.all(), many=True)
    return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
```

Thank you for help. Best regards.

Comment: [The documentation](https://www.datatables.net/manual/ajax) has a lot of useful information about how to format your source data.

Comment: If you want to show flat data in your datatable as per your example, then I would suggest to also create a flat JSON response in your view function. So just combine the data you need in your view function that feeds the datatable. Please post your code to that view function if you have any issues with it.

Comment: The JSON sample in your question is (a) not valid JSON; and (b) probably does not match the structure of the JSON you are actually using, since it does not contain an array `[ ... ]`. Can you edit the JSON sample to be more realistic of what you are actually using?

Comment: Appreciate for feedbacks. I updated the code(view.py - json - serializer.py). If JSON format is valid now, how can I create a flat json at view.py?

Comment: Your updated JSON does not have any nested arrays - which means there is only ever one `source_samples` object and one `projects` object for each record. If this is truly how your JSON is structured, then you can simply refer to the fields you need using dot-notation in your DataTables columns - for example: `{ data: 'id' }` (simple field); and `{ data: 'source_samples.type' }` (nested field); and `{ data: 'projects.prefix' }` (another nested field) - and so on. See [nested objects](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/deep.html) for more info.

Comment: In other words, there is no need to _flatten_ your data. It is already (effectively) flat enough for DataTables to use without any changes. (By the way, your JSON is still not valid - it is missing some commas - probably just a copy/paste problem.)

Comment: Thanks guys. { data: 'projects.prefix' } way worked well! I am able to display my data on table and it is super quick since get it by json format.